# CredentialsContainer get() method no more filtering password type credentials

Tags: google-chrome, credentials, credential-manager

I have few apps hosted on different subdomains. Each app does not share login credentials with each other.

E.g.

- app1.example.com - username: test1, password: test
- app2.example.com - username: test2, password: test
- app3.example.com - username: test3, password: test

So I implemented a login method for Chrome users through the CredentialsContainer: **get()** method like so:

```
await navigator.credentials.get({ password: true })
```

Up until Chrome v116 and upon calling the get() method, the browser was prompting showing a list with only the credentials for the current subdomain. So that an user was not seeing unrelated credentials.

However since the last update to v117, the browser is now showing all the credentials associated to the domain (example.com).

Does anyone know how to make it works like in v116? Or if there is an alternative approach to achieve the same?

I tried to Google for the changes between the 2 version but no much from it